# How to close a https stream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, stream, ndjson

I'm loading a `.ndjson` file via https. I want to close it after reading 100 lines of the file.

```
  const amount = 100;
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    var { statusCode } = res;

    if (statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new Error(`Request Failed.\n Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
    }

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let rows = [];
    res
      .pipe(ndjson.parse())
      .on('data', function (obj) {
        rows.push(obj);
        if (rows.length === amount) {
          this.end();
        }
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve(rows);
      });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  });
```

But every way I have tried the close the stream, the same error message appears:

```
Error: Could not parse row {"username"...
    at DestroyableTransform.parseRow [as mapper] (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\ndjson\index.js:19:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.flush [as _flush] (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\split2\index.js:44:21)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:138:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at prefinish (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:596:14)
    at finishMaybe (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:604:5)
    at afterWrite (C:\Users\thoma\Documents\GitHub\test\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:470:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:144:20)
```

And the stream works fine when not forcefully closed, so it isn't related to the `ndjson` file. Is it possible to close the stream in the middle of the request?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions :

1. Send a header to close the connection : `this.set("Connection", "close")`
2. Ending stream thanks to `this.end()`

I do not know which one is the best.

So, in your example, you have an issue due to [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (I recommand you to take a look to this link). Try the following code :

```
res
  .pipe(ndjson.parse())
  .on('data', obj => {
    rows.push(obj);
    if (rows.length === amount) {
      this.end();
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    resolve(rows);
  });
```